# Change arrowhead of arrows()

Tags: r, plot

i wonder if it is possible to change the arrowhead of an arrow drawn with `arrows()`. I looked through the documentation but all I found is that I can change the end of a line but not of an arrow?

```
plot(c(1:10))
arrows(0,0,10,10)
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What do you want to change the arrowhead to?

Comment: For example: I wanted the arrowhead to be solid instead of openend. With the example below I reached this by doing lwd=8 and shortening the length of the arrowhead.

Comment: suspected as much; base graphics arrows don't allow easy modification, other then the work-arounds you mention. Lattice graphics has `panel.arrows()` which takes a `type` argument where one can specify `"open"` or `"closed"` if you ever have need of Lattice plots. Shame this functionality isn't in base `arrows()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

as explained in `?arrow` , you can use `length` and `angle` to change the appearance of standard arrows. With `lwd` you can change the thickness, exactly like in lines(). Also `lty` works, although the result is often not exactly nice.

A whole set of examples :

```
plot(c(0:10),type="n")

arrows(1,0,2,1,length=0.2,angle=20)
arrows(1,1,2,2,length=0.1,angle=40,lwd=3)

invisible(mapply(arrows,
        rep(c(3,6),each=4),rep(3:6,2),
        rep(c(5,8),each=4),rep(5:8,2),
        angle=seq(10,40,length.out=8),
        length=rep(seq(0.1,0.3,length.out=4),2),
        lwd=rep(1:4,each=2))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I have misunderstood the documentation. Thank you for providing example code.

Comment: @Sarah : you can also play with eg. `lwd` to change the thickness of the lines. See adapted code.

Comment: Adding these examples of how to use the length, angle, and lwd might be a useful patch to `?arrows`.  Would you consider submitting a patch?

Comment: Thanks, as I commented above I have created a solid arrowhead with lwd=8 and a shorter length of the arrwohead.

Answer (score 19):

Karline Soetaert's package [`shape`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shape/) is useful for this purpose:

```
library(shape)
plot(c(0,2),c(-2,2), col=NA)
Arrows(c(0,1.7),c(1.3,-1.8),c(0.8,1.1),c(1.2,-1), lwd=2)
```

The default is a filled, curved arrowhead that's pleasant to look at:

[image]

*Gotta love CRAN!*

Comment: Do you know if these arrows can also be used in ggplot2 plots by any chance?

Comment: this seems to break in logplots

Answer (score 6):

If the other answers don't give you enough control of your arrows using the arrows function, you can use the function `my.symbols`, from `TeachingDemos` package. This allows you to create your own custom arrows and plot them.

The function `ms.arrows`, in the same package, shows one method of doing this: you can modify that function (or other `ms.*` functions) to create any type of arrow you want, and later use `my.symbols` to plot them.

**Edit**

Here is an example as requested:

```
library(TeachingDemos)

ms.arrowhead <- function(angle, ...) {
  xy <- cbind( c(-1, -0.75, -1, 0), 
               c(-0.5, 0, 0.5, 0) )
  xy <- xy %*% matrix(c(cos(angle),-sin(angle),sin(angle),cos(angle)), 2)
  xspline(xy, shape=c(0, -1, 0, 0), open=FALSE, ...)
}

plot(1:10, 1:10)
my.symbols(1:10, 1:10, ms.arrows, angle=seq(pi, 0, length=10),
           col='blue', adj=1, length=0, symb.plots=TRUE)
my.symbols(1:10, 1:10, ms.arrowhead, angle= seq(pi, 0, length=10), 
           col='green', inches=0.5, lwd=2, symb.plots = TRUE)
```

This uses the `xspline` function to draw a triangle with a curved back as the arrowhead.  The points can be modified to get a different shaped arrowhead, or another method can be used for the shape.

Comment: Can you add a sample of how to use this?

Comment: @retorquere, I have added one example.