# R plot rotated points or filled arrowhead

Tags: r, plot, points, arrows, pch

is there a way in basic R to modify the pch point types by just rotating them? I´d need a pointing-right triangle (with its base parallel to the y axes).

```
x <- runif(5)
y <- runif(5)
plot(x, y, pch = 17, cex = 2)   #is there a parameter for rotation?
```

Alternatively, how could I change the arrowhead in arrows() with a filled triangle?

```
plot(x, y, pch = "")
arrows(x, y, x-0.03, y, code = 1)   #is there a parameter for the arrowhead symbol?
```

thanks for your help!

Sara

Comment: Look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731432/change-arrowhead-of-arrows

Comment: `pch = -9658` (maybe depending on the execution environment)

Comment: Thank you! @cuttlefish44 ´s solution it the straightforward way I was looking for : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in my windows environment, `pch` can take almost all characters that WGL4 contains. For example, *BLACK RIGHT-POINTING POINTER* is drawn by `pch = -9658`, `pch = -as.hexmode("25BA")`, or `pch = "\U25BA"`. You can get codes of characters from [Using special characters from Windows Glyph List 4 (WGL4) in HTML](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wgl4.html).

for example;

```
plot(rep(1, 9), pch = -c(9658, 9668, 9674, 9688, 9689, 9786, 9788, 9824, 9827), cex = 2)
```

[image]