# ggplot - How can I add a ":)" instead of the actual emoji of a smiley face?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I would like to add within the `scale_shape_manual()` of a `ggplot` a smiley face for a given category, but simple, so exactly as ":)".
However, I can only find an actual emoji (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957167/r-plot-rotated-points-or-filled-arrowhead) or more options here: https://www.alanwood.net/demos/wgl4.html).

So, for example with a categorical variable with 3 levels, I would have:

```
scale_shape_manual(values = c(-9786, as.hexmode("3F"), as.hexmode("78")))
```

But I want that `-9786` to be ":)" and not the emoji (codes from:  https://www.alanwood.net/demos/wgl4.html)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can your emojis using a `geom_text`. Shapes only support a single character. See e.g. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#sec:shape-spec

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @stefan you can use the `geom_text` function to display some text (smileys :)) by creating them as a `label`. Since you didn't provide reproducible example I tried to create one. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) # colors of ggplot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +  
  geom_text(aes(color = factor(group), label = label)) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = df$label,
                     values = hue_pal()(4))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:4,
                 y = 1:4,
                 group = c(1:4),
                 label = c(":)", ";)", ":(", ";("))
```

Comment: This does work in this context, but how to add it with other symbols, within scale_shape_manual()? I updated the question, as it is indeed not very clear